# PHP. Безопасность. Авторизация

Tags: php, безопасность, авторизация

Пишу авторизацию для сайта на php. Возник вопрос по поводу безопасности при реализации функции "запомнить меня".

Если вкратце, то пользователю выдаются cookie с токеном, который сформирован следующим методом:

```
$bytes = random_bytes(rand(150, 267));
$token = bin2hex($bytes);
```

Сохраняем его в базу данных и выдаём пользователю.
При последующей идентификации сверяется токен и пользователь авторизован.

Вопрос: возможно ли методом перебора комбинаций несанкционированно авторизоваться на сайте? Может лучше идентифицировать пользователя по двум параметрам: например его id в базе данных и сформированному токену?

Comment: Конечно возможно. Всегда будет возможно. Просто в некоторых случаях подбирать токен будет неоправданно дорого. И зачем изобретать велосипед? воспользуйтесь чем-нибудь вроде random_bytes()

Comment: По поводу двух параметров - конечно безопасность повысится. Еще более она повысится при двухфакторной аутентификации. Вопрос в умении вовремя остановиться))

Comment: Вы ещё не забывайте аннулировать все токены пользователя при смене пароля

Comment: Как уже сказали, не изобретайте велик, `password_hash` и `password_verify`, избавят от возможной головной боли. Перебрать нереально, если зоморочишься и к хэшу примешаешь свою соль.

Comment: @Borislav password_hash к данной задаче не имеет вообще никакого отношения